# Conditions for the existence of a steady state in time-driven system

Tags: time-evolution, dissipation, open-quantum-systems, steady-state

Consider an open quantum system given by the Hamiltonian

$$H = H_B + H_S(t) + H_{SB}$$

with $B$ denoting the noninteracting bath, $H_S(t)$ the time-dependent noninteracting system and $H_{SB}$ is a linear coupling between system and bath.

The dynamics of the reduced density matrix $\sigma = \mathrm{tr}_B \{\rho\}$ is given by

$$\dot{\sigma} = \mathcal{L}(t)[\sigma] + \mathcal{D}(t).$$

My question is: Which condition should the superoperators $\mathcal{L}, \mathcal{D}$ fulfill such that a unique steady state exists (in the sense $\dot{\sigma}_\mathrm{ss} = 0$ and that for all $\sigma(t_0)$ it holds $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \vert \sigma(t)-\sigma_{ss}\vert = 0$).

Assuming that the system and bath consists of noninteracting fermions, the Dissipator can be solved within the hierarchical equation of motion approach or within Keldysh nonequilibrium Green functions, as described [in this paper](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/18/9/093044), and can be made to be independent of the reduced density matrix $\sigma$. So once the solution $\mathcal{D}(t)$ is known, the equation of motion for the reduced density matrix is in principle a time-dependent linear non-homogeneous system.
The time-independent case is clear to me. Suppose, $\mathcal{L}$ is time-independent and there exists a unique steady-state for the dissipator, $\mathcal{D}_\infty = \lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}\mathcal{D}(t)$, then the steady state RDM is (working in Liouville-space)

$$\sigma_\mathrm{ss} = - \mathcal{L}^{-1}\mathcal{D}_\infty.$$

That means that a unique steady-state exists, iff $\mathcal{D}_\infty$ exists and $\mathcal{L}$ is non-singular.

What about the case, in which $\mathcal{L}(t)$ is time-dependent, e.g. due to a time-dependence of $H_S(t)$? The formal solution of the problem would be given by

$$\sigma(t) = \mathrm{e}^{\int_0^t \mathcal{L}(s)\mathrm{d} s} \int_0^t \mathrm{e}^{-\int_0^t \mathcal{L}(s)\mathrm{d} s}\mathcal{D}(s)\mathrm{d}s,$$

but how should one take the limit $t\rightarrow \infty$, e.g. if $\mathcal{L}(t)$ is a (quasi-)periodic superoperator? I am familiar with Floquet-theory, and I see that if could be of help here. Greatly appreciate any references to similar types of problems!